# Fetching an element from a list within a note through automator/scripting

Tags: applescript, automator, notes.app

I have a notes file containing a list of names. Is there a way I can copy one of them through automator or through scripting without me having to open the notes app?

Notes as in the default notes app for Mac.

Thank you

-Edit for clarification:

- The type of list that I am using is the one with a little buble that lets you tick or untick the elements. To keep this type of list would be ideal but not necessary.
- This would be the beginnings of a script that would allow to me to store that line of the list into a variable as a string so that it can be used afterwards.
- My version of macOS is Ventura 13.4.1

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you provide an example? Also, what version of macOS are you on (there are subtle differences in scripting syntax across versions).

Comment: @Allan Hi Allan, truth is I am very new to any of this and any of the documentation that I have been reading only managed to confuse me, so I can't really provide you with any examples of what I have been doing cause there is none. My macOs version is Ventura 13.4.1

Comment: Totally fair - even Apple doesn’t document AppleScript well; I myself had to resort to third party reference material.   One thing I do suggest, as the question is a pretty big “ask” in terms of the script is to break it down into individual tasks.  Maybe start with extracting/copying text from an existing note?

Comment: Notes are normally stored in a SQLite database, and exports are PDF - what kind of file do you have?